# Java Library to generate interactive Graph

Tags: java, graph, visualization, graphviz

i want to visualize our SOA services as graph. we have business services and domain services.

```
                        -> domain service 1
e.g. business service 1 -> domain service 2
                        -> domain service 3
```

i currently use graphviz/dot to generate the graph - all good so far. the graph is quite big. now i am looking for a tool that allows me to genereate "interactive" graphs where i can click on a node (a business service) and it will be centered into the view and all its dependencies (other nodes) are aligned around it.

is there any library that can do that? i already looked at "JUNG" and did't find an example that achieves this.

looking forward to your replies

marcel
ps: if there are non java tools i would also be interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java

- [Netbeans Visual library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/)
- [Prefuse](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse)

Javascript:

- [D3](http://d3js.org/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/) (Predecessor to D3)
- [JavaScript Infovis toolkit](http://thejit.org/)

Flash

- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)