# VTK alternatives

Tags: vtk, graph-drawing

I apologize if the answer was already somewhere, searching the interwebs did not return me the answer(s) I was looking for.

Situation : I have a small graph (a set of Edges and Nodes that is) - Now I want to display it in an interactive manner, and I would like to manipulate the display styles and symbols that are used for edges and nodes, programetically.

Hence kgraphviewer wont work - i want to do it programetically as stated.

I noticed VTK, comes with a lot of built is graph drawing algorithms. But seems to be a really large one.

Question : What are some alternatives to VTK ? Graphviz is probably one, but I can not confirm that graphviz comes with all the graph drawing algorithms as VTK - any other possibly smaller options, with all the built in graphs?

Side note : Some systems uses a static drawign widget, i.e. once the drawing is displayed, in an widget that the system comes with, you can not interact with the drawing using your mouse. The GNU implementation of IDL, GDL, has this problem. I would Like to avoid this.

Comment: SO doesn't do recommendations, so your question is off-topic.  You might be interested in https://gephi.org

Comment: @Sean: Do you have some preferences about the programming language? This could help in giving an answer.

Comment: @Andrea : No, I am open to any possible languages that run on a linux platform

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with you regarding the VTK's consideration: it's a powerful toolkit but it is (maybe) too much "big", and it's not so easy to configure a working VTK environment. 
I don't have a great experience in the field of graphs, but a search leads to [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513824/java-library-to-generate-interactive-graph). I think that [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/), listed under the Java section, could be of some interest. C++ itself seems to have a lot of choices, listed in various answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296199/is-there-any-out-of-the-box-2d-3d-plotting-library-for-c). I hope that it will help.

Answer (score -1):

I used Gephi public domain graph visualization software on Linux.  It was a quick way to get a 3 D. Picture which can be modified with line thickness to show an edge weight - good for comm network work.